# Why doesn't this IPv6 listen directive also accept IPv4?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ipv6, ipv4

In my nginx (1.4.2) setup on Ubuntu 12.04, I have set up only **one** configuration file (I deleted/disabled the others):

```
server {
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  location / {
    root /home/lwood/websites/default/public;
  }
}
```

I have restarted nginx.

Why does nginx not accept IPv4 connections? Here are the docs

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#listen

They mention that

> In Linux by default any IPv6 TCP socket also accepts IPv4 traffic ... the runtime parameter: net.ipv6.bindv6only which has the value 0 by default.

I have checked with `sysctl`, bindv6only is indeed set to 0. So my IPv6 listen directive should accept IPv4 as well, right?

I must be misunderstanding the docs. An explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wiki is out of date. As specified in [the *actual* documentation](http://nginx.org/r/listen), the default for `ipv6only` is `on` since nginx 1.3.4. If you omit the parameter, then nginx will only bind to IPv6. The OS settings are never used.