# Binding stunnel on both IPv6 and IPv4

Tags: ssl, ipv6, stunnel

I would like to make a local unencrypted service that listens on 127.0.0.1:8000 available via SSL on both IPv4 and IPv6 on port 8001.

Unfortunately, stunnel configuration

```
[Server]
accept = 8001
connect = 8000
```

binds only on IPv4, as I have checked via netstat and ncat:

```
~$ sudo netstat -an|grep 800 | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

~$ ncat --ssl -v ::1 8001
Ncat: Version 6.46 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connection refused.
```

However, the port seems to be blocked also on IPv6. When I add

```
[Server IPv6]
accept = :::8001
connect = 8000
```

stunnel will not start, since the port is blocked:

```
[ ] Service [pyload Web] (FD=7) bound to 0.0.0.0:8001
[!] Error binding service [pyload Web IPv6] to :::8001
[!] bind: Address already in use (98)
```

I have tried both orders for the respective sections in my stunnel config file. I am using version 5.02 from the Ubuntu Utopic repository. Any ideas?

Comment: show `netstat -an | grep 8000 | grep LISTEN` for a first configuration fragment.

Comment: I have included the outputs in my question now.

Comment: what error message exaclty are you getting ?

Comment: Added it to my question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I found an answer myself. [Why doesn't this IPv6 listen directive also accept IPv4?](https://serverfault.com/questions/540693/why-doesnt-this-ipv6-listen-directive-also-accept-ipv4?rq=1) states from the nginx doc that

```
In Linux by default any IPv6 TCP socket also accepts IPv4 traffic 
... the runtime parameter: net.ipv6.bindv6only which has the value 0 by default.
```

So I used ONLY the [Server IPv6]. This gives only a tcp6 entry in netstat, but I am also able to connect via IPv4.

This also explains the behaviour, since stunnel implicitly tries to bin to the IPv4 port in the v6 section. I am unsure if my solution is good practice and if one can rely in the net.ipv6 default. I think there should be a ipv6only option in stunnel, like there is for nginx and socat.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get both ipv4 and ipv6 to work at the same time on my ubuntu 16.04 machine (a Linode) I had to configure stunnel to bind to *all* ipv6 addresses, like this:

```
accept = :::443
```

Specifying a particular ipv6 address would bind successfully to that one address, but would not allow ipv4 requests to go through.

```
accept = ipv6.sqlite.org:443  ;# Does not accept IPv4
```